# CSS keyframes change background-image(SVG) is displaced in Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari, jquery-animate, background-image

I'm trying to make a dynamic logo on http://calligraphic.fr/ with css keyframes.
Every keyframe has a different background image.
It looks great on Chrome but on Safari it displaces the background image at certain keyframes.
I tried everything to solve this, I hope someone can help me.

```
@keyframes worldtrip {
      0% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-first-01.svg); }
      3% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-2-01.svg); }
      6% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-3-01.svg); }
      9% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-4-01.svg); }
      12% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-5-01.svg); }
      15% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-6-01.svg); }
      18% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-7-01.svg); }
      21% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-8-01.svg); }
      24% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-9-01.svg); }
      27% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-10-01.svg); }
      30% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-11-01.svg); }
      33% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-12-01.svg); }
      36% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-13-01.svg); }
      39% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-first-01.svg); }
    100% {   background-image: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-first-01.svg); }

}
```

```
.q_logo::before {
    pointer-events: none!important;
        animation: 4s none 0s infinite worldtrip;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: url(https://calligraphic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/caligraphic-logo-first-01.svg);
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-size: 135px!important;
    background-size: 500px 500px!important;
    background-position: center top!important;
    margin-top: -55px!important;
    z-index: 999;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It is kinda brutal to load a file for every 'sprite/keyframe'  Since you have the SVG source, it is a matter of copy paste into one SVG file and create a proper spritesheet you can play with CSS animation steps; see: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/03/different-ways-to-use-svg-sprites-in-animation/

Comment: I put the animation-duration to 10 times what you have (4s->40s) to see exactly where each frame was going. Same result on Safari as on Edge/Chrome - some of the placing of the pen is a bit strange, but the most noticeable thing is a gap between frames 5 and 6.

Comment: ...8-01.svg has a gap in it - is that intentional?

Comment: Hi @a-haworth, Yes, it is intentional seeing the pen has to go behind the earth. The issue is that the background size and position changes each frame.

Comment: @danny-365csi-engelman Thats a really good idea! I will try to make 1 spritesheet! Thank you